# ajax return value from php pass in to id and display on page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i created post and comment system in my webpage. i have different Post on my index.php, now when i comment on any post its sending comment text and post id to comment.php and inserting comment to that particular post id record in mysql and return back with comment text though ajax, where it need to be shown below related post.

problem is return comment text is showing under first record on the page. but it should be shown under related post. below is my jquery

```
$(function onLoaded(){
$(document).on('submit','.comment_p',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var com_dis= $(this).find("#comment_disc").val();
if(com_dis=='')
     {
    alert('Please add your comment');
     } else{
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/comment_update.php",
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data){
         //alert(data);
    $("#flash").html(data);
           }
       });
     }

    }); 
});
```

and in index page

```
<div id="flash"></div>
```

exmaple image

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036095/how-to-add-an-element-always-as-last-element-using-jquery as well i recommend to you that not return again all the HTML comment code throught ajax, Maybe just return true/false (json better) and if is true do wathever in the client side with the form data and not with the ajax result data. Depends on what you do with the form data at server side.

Comment: i need to display comment which is return through ajax to the related post. but all return comment showing under first post. not on related post. i dont have much knowledge in ajax i tried $(this) but did't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its difficult to give a solution without seeing your html, so the below code is assuming the ID of the original comment is: comment_X (where X is the numerical ID) and that you are able to get the COMMENT ID in a variable called comment_id

change **$("#flash").html(data);**

to
    **$("comment_" + comment_id).append(data);**

Comment: thank you for your replay i did similar to this $("#flash"+ID).append(data);
$("#comment_disc"+ID).val('');
$("#comment_disc"+ID).focus();
 and <div id=flash'$row['id']'></div